# Unable to determine spinner value

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

I have been on here for over an hour now reading related questions, but have not yet found a solution that fixes my issue, so I will ask.

I have a Spinner. I would like to use the selected city in that spinner to set a latitude and longitude variable. I am unable to figure out how to either directly call that information, or to make it set into a variable when the "use this city" button is clicked. Here is the code I have so far.

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="locations">
    <item > Washington D.C. </item>      
    <item >New York, NY</item> 
    <item >Juneau, AL</item>
    </string-array>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package cl.telematica.locationexample;

   import      cl.telematica.locationexample.interfaces.LocationListenerHandler;
   import cl.telematica.locationexample.location.ActiveLocationManagerActivity;


    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActiveLocationManagerActivity {

    public static String citylatitudText;
    public static String citylongitudText;
    public static TextView latitudText;
    public static TextView longitudText;
    public static String locationSet;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        /*ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        locationSet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                locationSet);

         setListAdapter(adapter);*/
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTestNoResults);
    Button c = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGPSSearch);
    Button d = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSetCity);

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> location_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.locations, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    location_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(location_adapter);

    //final String locationSet = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    //final String locationSet = spinner.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
   // spinner.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>)spinner.getAdapter()).getPosition(locationSet));

    //final String locationSet = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoResults.class));
            };
        });
        c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //if ()
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewSearch.class));
            };
        });

        d.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if( locationSet == "Washington D.C.")
                { citylatitudText = "38.9047 N";
                citylongitudText = "77.0164 W";
                }

                else if (locationSet == "New York, NY")
                {citylatitudText = "40.7127° N";
                citylongitudText = "74.0059° W";            
                }
                else
                {citylatitudText = "58.3000° N";
                citylongitudText = "134.4167° W";           
                }

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewSearch.class));
            };
        });
        latitudText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        longitudText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        listener = new LocationListenerHandler() {
            @Override
            public void OnLocationReceived(Location loc) {
                latitudText.setText("" + loc.getLatitude());
                longitudText.setText("" + loc.getLongitude());
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

NewSearch.java

```
package cl.telematica.locationexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import cl.telematica.locationexample.location.ActiveLocationManagerActivity;

public class NewSearch extends ActiveLocationManagerActivity {

    public TextView citylat;
    public TextView citylong;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_search);
        citylat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        citylong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        citylat.setText(""+ MainActivity.citylatitudText);
        //citylong.setText("" + MainActivity.citylongitudText);
        citylong.setText("" + MainActivity.locationSet);//testing to see if the city name selected by spinner is being put in variable form


    }

}
```

When I click on the "use this city" button, I am getting the word "null" for the citylong variable on the NewSearch page, and "58.3000° N" for the citylat (so it is going to the "else" statement, regardless of what city I select).

I know there are other posts about calling from a Spinner, and you can see where I have tried some of them and left them commented out in my code because they didnt work.

I appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: just curious, where are you updating the spinner with the items from strings xml?

Comment: I have the following in my activity_main.xml
        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/select_location"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:entries="@array/locations" />

And this line in my MainActivity.java
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting on that comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. Here is my code as it is right now (working! yay!)

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActiveLocationManagerActivity {

    public static String citylatitudText;
    public static String citylongitudText;
    public static TextView latitudText;
    public static TextView longitudText;
    public static String locationSet;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTestNoResults);
        Button c = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGPSSearch);
        Button d = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSetCity);

        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {           
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoResults.class));
            };
        });
        c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {           
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewSearch.class));
            };
        });

        d.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String locationSet = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
                if( locationSet.equals("Washington D.C.") )
                { citylatitudText = "38.9047 N";
                citylongitudText = "77.0164 W";
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Mansfield, PA"))
                {citylatitudText = "41.8061 N";
                citylongitudText = "77.0756 W";         
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals( "New York, NY"))
                {citylatitudText = "40.7127° N";
                citylongitudText = "74.0059° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals( "Juneau, AL"))
                {citylatitudText = "58.3000° N";
                citylongitudText = "134.4167° W";           
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Phoenix, AZ"))
                {citylatitudText = "33.4500° N";
                citylongitudText = "112.0667° W";           
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Tucson, AZ"))
                {citylatitudText = "32.2217° N";
                citylongitudText = "110.9264° W";           
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals( "Sacramento, CA"))
                {citylatitudText = "38.5556° N";
                citylongitudText = "121.4689° W";           
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("San Diego, CA"))
                {citylatitudText = "32.7150° N";
                citylongitudText = "117.1625° W";           
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Los Angeles, CA"))
                {citylatitudText = "34.0500° N";
                citylongitudText = "118.2500° W";           
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Denver, CO"))
                {citylatitudText = "39.7392° N";
                citylongitudText = "104.9903° W";           
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Jacksonville, FL"))
                {citylatitudText = "30.3369° N";
                citylongitudText = "81.6614° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Orlando, FL"))
                {citylatitudText = "28.4158° N";
                citylongitudText = "81.2989° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Atlanta, GA"))
                {citylatitudText = "33.7550° N";
                citylongitudText = "84.3900° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Boise, ID"))
                {citylatitudText = "43.6167° N";
                citylongitudText = "116.2000° W";           
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Chicago, IL"))
                {citylatitudText = "41.8369° N";
                citylongitudText = "87.6847° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Indianapolis, IN"))
                {citylatitudText = "39.7910° N";
                citylongitudText = "86.1480° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Des Moines, IA"))
                {citylatitudText = "41.5908° N";
                citylongitudText = "93.6208° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Kansas City, KS"))
                {citylatitudText = "39.1067° N";
                citylongitudText = "94.6764° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Louisville, KY"))
                {citylatitudText = "38.2500° N";
                citylongitudText = "85.7667° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("New Orleans, LA"))
                {citylatitudText = "29.9500° N";
                citylongitudText = "90.0667° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Portland, ME"))
                {citylatitudText = "43.6667° N";
                citylongitudText = "70.2667° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Baltimore, MD"))
                {citylatitudText = "39.2833° N";
                citylongitudText = "76.6167° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Boston, MA"))
                {citylatitudText = "42.3601° N";
                citylongitudText = "71.0589° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Detroit, MI"))
                {citylatitudText = "42.3314° N";
                citylongitudText = "83.0458° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Minneapolis, MN"))
                {citylatitudText = "44.9778° N";
                citylongitudText = "93.2650° W";            
                }
                else if (locationSet.equals("Seattle, WA"))
                {citylatitudText = "47.6097° N";
                citylongitudText = "122.3331° W";           
                }
                else
                {citylatitudText = "39.9500° N";
                citylongitudText = "75.1667° W";            
                }               
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewSearch.class));
            };
        });
        latitudText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        longitudText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        listener = new LocationListenerHandler() {
            @Override
            public void OnLocationReceived(Location loc) {
                latitudText.setText("" + loc.getLatitude());
                longitudText.setText("" + loc.getLongitude());
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While comparing the strings, can you try using the equals method?

```
    if( locationSet.equals("Washington D.C."))
```

And try getting the string value from the spinner after the button is clicked. Include

```
    final String locationSet = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
```

within the

```
     d.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

method. I had faced similar problems and these hacks helped me fix it. And you may face some lag/process issues if you are running on an emulator, so try it by installing it in a mobile.

Let me know if this helped.

Update 1:

This could be completely wrong, but this is how I implemented my Spinner.

1. First use an array adapter to update and set the items in the Spinner and tell the code what they are. So, to do it in your code

   ```
   ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> location_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.locations, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
   lang_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   spinner.setAdapter(location_adapter);
   ```

I found this missing in your code. I guess this should work.

Comment: Still getting "null' for the citylong variable on the NewSearch page. :(

Comment: Did you mean to use that code to initialize my spinner? I have updated my MainActivity.java code to reflect what I think you meant . Can you confirm that it correct?

Comment: are you trying it on an emulator or on a phone?

Comment: Nexus 7 tablet. The emulator is too slow to use for anything.  :) I did get it figured out though and have updated my code.